# Microsoft excel security warning excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a excel worksheet in which I do import data from external web page by this following method:

Data-> Get external data -> From Web

This data gets auto refreshed every 15 min.

While refreshing data automatically, quite often I receive a error message as attached below link. I tried several times installing this certificate, but the error still remains as it is.

How can I fix it?

[image: ERROR IMAGE, CLICK HERE]

Comment: Where are you fetching the data? Is it a HTTPS website with valid certificates? The error is pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes, its a HTTPS website here it's the link [link](https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=28NOV2019)

Comment: How can by pass this warning message by VBA code or by any other tool?